# Python - permission denied installing pymongo

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `pymongo` and getting permission denied when I do:

```
pip install pymongo
Collecting pymongo
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/84/b329b5debc71693111780b389222897949f084a833dd996b4e7a36c839fc/pymongo-3.11.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (492kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 501kB 2.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 365, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 789, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 854, in install
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1069, in move_wheel_files
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 287, in clobber
    ensure_dir(dest)  # common for the 'include' path
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6'
```

If I try to specify the `--user` flag it claims that there's no module by that name available:

```
python aws_ec2_list_instances.py --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ec2_mongo import insert_doc,set_db,mongo_export_to_file
  File "/home/tdun0002/stash/cloud_scripts/aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/ec2_mongo.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pymongo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: You probably should use virtual environments. Read on the topic first. Maybe here: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments and https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `--user` flag for installing modules for single user. You said that you tried to use `--user` but you used it while running python file. You should install before running.

So, you can use `--user` flag. You can use `pip install --user pymongo`

Comment: Yeah, but if I do that, I'll have to `sudo` each time I want to run my script. I would rather not have to do that. My user won't have access to that python module if I do it that way. I think there is a flag you can use to install it for your local user that would allow that but I can't recall it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should use `pip install --user pymongo` for installing modules for single user. You said that you tried to use `--user` but you used it while running python file. You should install before running

Comment: Thanks. Using `pip install --user pymongo` did the trick. I agree that you should never `sudo` with pip.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer? I edited my answer